# How python jira lib to change issue's resolution

Tags: python, jira, python-jira

I try to update an issue's resolution through python jira lib, but get below error.

```py
>>> jp=JiraProject('VCART', 'https://jira.microhard.com')
>>> _issue=jp.issue('VCART-4046')
>>> _issue.update({'Resolution': {'name': 'Done'}})

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jira/resources.py", line 485, in update
    super(Issue, self).update(async_=async_, jira=jira, notify=notify, fields=data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jira/resources.py", line 233, in update
    self.self + querystring, data=data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jira/resilientsession.py", line 157, in put
    return self.__verb('PUT', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jira/resilientsession.py", line 147, in __verb
    raise_on_error(response, verb=verb, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jira/resilientsession.py", line 57, in raise_on_error
    r.status_code, error, r.url, request=request, response=r, **kwargs)
jira.exceptions.JIRAError: JiraError HTTP 400 url: https://jira.microhard.com/rest/api/2/issue/4559852
    text: Field 'Resolution' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown.
    
    response headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'close', 'X-AREQUESTID': '407x17688874x7', 'X-ASESSIONID': '1l8dfq5', 'X-ANODEID': 'jira1prda2', 'Referrer-Policy': 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin', 'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000', 'X-Seraph-LoginReason': 'OK', 'X-RateLimit-Limit': '500', 'X-RateLimit-Remaining': '499', 'X-RateLimit-FillRate': '40', 'X-RateLimit-Interval-Seconds': '5', 'Retry-After': '0', 'X-AUSERNAME': 'buildaudit', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, no-transform', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Vary': 'User-Agent', 'Date': 'Wed, 30 Nov 2022 14:47:38 GMT'}
    response text = {"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"Resolution":"Field 'Resolution' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown."}}
```

Below neither works

```py
 _issue.update({"fields": {"resolution": {"name": "Closed"}}})
```

The status of current issue is `Reopened`

Answer (score 0):

In the UI there is the long-standing Atlassian-suggested approach of adding a global self-transition to all statuses in a workflow, withe a Resolution screen. Then bulk transition the issues back to the same status. More info at
https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloudkb/best-practices-on-using-the-resolution-field-968660796.html#Bestpracticesonusingthe%22Resolution%22field-Thefollowinginstructionsaremeanttocorrectpreviousissuesthathavetheresolutionfieldincorrectlyset.

Then there is the way that admins with ScriptRunner do it, using the built-in script to fix resolutions.

To script this with an external call is harder. I guess reopening the issue and then setting the resolution when closing it again is possible, though slow

Comment: But the issue is already `Reopened`